# Perl search and replace substring

Tags: regex, string, perl, search, replace

How can I search and replace a substring using perl script?

for example --> txt1.txt

```
Hi/hello #55
Hi/hi #55
```

how can search for variable1 in txt1.txt, if found replace it with variable2. 
There can be any number after hashtag between 0-100. I would like to search for 
"Hi/hello" first and if found, replace whole content "Hi/hello #(0-100)" with "Hi/hello #60;

mytry.txt

```
my $variable1="Hi/hello #(0-100)";
my $variable2="Hi/hello #60;
print "$short\n";
system(q{perl -pe"s|($ENV{variable1} *)#\d+|$ENV{variable2}|;" txt1.p4sm  > txt2.p4sm});
```

desiredoutput.txt

```
Hi/hello #60
Hi/hi #55
```

Comment: What you are trying to run there looks very strange.

Comment: Indeed, it's pretty strange... About string replacement - it would be good if you provided example data before and after replacement, and then verbosely explain what was replaced and why. At this time `Hi/Hello` can be interpreted by people as actual string, or that either `Hi` or `hello` should be accepted...

Comment: apologize for confusion, i have updated my original question..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing doesn't make much sense, if you are already inside of a Perl script don't shell out to perform a Perl one-liner, just write a simple loop to solve your problem.

The easiest way to do this is to create a pattern that matches what you would like, then perform a substitution on a line-by-line basis. The example below uses the `DATA` filehandle, but that can be replaced by a filehandle pointing to the source file you would like to modify:

```
use strict; 
use warnings; 

my $pattern = qr|(Hi/hello) #\((\d{1,3})\)|;
while ( my $row = <DATA> ) {
   # enforce restriction for 0-100
   if ( $row =~ m/$pattern/ && $2 >= 0 && $2 <= 100 ) {
      # replace with new suffix
      print $row =~ s/$pattern/$1 #(60)/gr;  
      next;
   }

   print $row;
}

__DATA__
Hi/hello #(1)
Hi/hello #(10)
Hi/hello #(100)
Hi/hello #(101)
```

output:

```
Hi/hello #(60)
Hi/hello #(60)
Hi/hello #(60)
Hi/hello #(101) <- ignored because it doesnt fall into range [0, 100]
```

regular expression explained:

```
(Hi/hello) #\((\d{1,3})\)
```

this regular expression matches and captures two pieces of data, the prefix "Hi/hello" and the number inside of `#(<number>)`. These are stored in `$1` and `$2` respectively.

Comment: Hunter, thank you for very quick reply. Few questions... can i use change it to my $pattern = qr|($variable1) #\((\d{1,3})\)|;? and also i'm getting Bareword found where operator expected near line "print $row =~ s/$pattern/$1 #(60)/gr;" and can also change it to variable2 instead of $pattern/$1 #(60)/gr... because it won't be 60 all the time i would simply like to replace it with variable2...

Comment: @Mihir then change the replace part to be `$variable2`

Answer (score 2):

Based on your description what you are looking for is as follows:

```
my $variable1="Hi/hello #(0-100)";
my $variable2="Hi/hello #60";
if($variable1 =~ /Hi\/hello/)
  {
    $variable1 =~ s/^.*$/$variable2/;
  }
```

I'm expecting there is more to it than this, but let's start there.

Comment: You miss the closing `"` in second line.